# Hibernate Example Criteria query: filtering by child properties

Tags: hibernate, criteria, query-by-example

I have done my fair amount of research and finally decided to ask this.

I have two classes like this:

```
Employee
-emp_id
-name
-dep_id

Department
-dep_id
-name
```

I'm using this code to query by example:

```
List<Employee> find = null;
Example example = Example.create(criteria)
        .excludeZeroes()
        .ignoreCase();
find = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Employee.class)
        .add(example)
        .list() ;
return find;
```

The criteria object is an instance of Employee and I want to retrieve all employees with a given department name.

The problem is that when I execute the code I get employees from all departments even when criteria has a property set like this:
   criteria.department.name = "IT"

It works correctly when the example has parent properties set but it does not filter on children properties.

From what I can see I have to create aliases to join child properties but that kind of defeats the purpose of the Example criteria.

Any comments on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A criteria created with `createCriteria(Department.class)` won't return employees. It will return Departments.

And an example query is used to retrieve entities which are the same as the example you pass as argument. But, as the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples) says:

> Version properties, identifiers and **associations are ignored**

Comment: You are right, it was an error when writing the question. I have updated it and marked it answered. I will modify the code to add criteria to filter by child entities as well. Thank you.